# how to add a custom mfc control to the dialog window?

Tags: layout, mfc, drawing, widget, controls

I've derived a class from CStatic in MFC. But I don't know how to add it to my dialog window.
This mfc application that I'm working on is a dialog based application.

In Gtk+ or Qt we could use layouts and add our widgets to them, but in mfc it doesn't seem to be such a mechanism. I'm wondering how is it possible for an custom made control to be added to another GUI element!!!

Please give me a simple example if you can.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technique you are looking for is **subclassing** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

There is a good sample on that page too.